# Print without line feed

Tags: python

How to print something in Python without added line feed at the end?

Something like `printf("abc")` (no `\n` at the end) in C or `process.stdout.write("abc")` in Node.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Python 3:

Use the `end` parameter of the [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to overwrite its default `'\n'` value, so that the function will not add a new line at the end:

```
print(text, end='')
```

#### Python 2:

Add a trailing comma to the [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

```
print text,
```

---

If you need a solution that works for both Python 2 and Python 3, you should consider importing the [`print` function in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print), so you can use the above Python 3 syntax on both. You can do that with the following line at the top of your module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Answer (score 3):

In python 2 (although this adds an extra space at the end of the text):

```
print "abc",
```

In python 3 (or python2 with `from __future__ import print_function`):

```
print("abc", end="")
```

This works in both 2 and 3:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("abc")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution try:

```
print("aze", end = "")
```

`end` set the end of line character (and `sep` the separator of sentences).
You can try:

```
print("hello", "my name", "is", sep="*", end = "w")
```